# Pandas: DataFrame.apply(f, axis=1) on an empty DataFrame ignores exceptions?

Tags: python, pandas

If the function being applied to an empty DataFrame raises an exception, an empty 
DataFrame is returned:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> def raise_exc(*a, **kw):
...   raise Exception()
... 
>>> empty = pd.DataFrame({"a": []})
>>> empty.apply(raise_exc, index=1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a]
Index: []
```

Why is this? Is there any reason it returns an empty DataFrame as opposed to either re-raising the exception (as is the case when the DataFrame isn't empty), or returning a Series (as it would normally do)?

Comment: Probably just an edge case that there's no test for.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the Pandas source, it looks like this is the culprit:

```
if not all(self.shape):
    # How to determine this better?
    is_reduction = False
    try:
        is_reduction = not isinstance(f(_EMPTY_SERIES), Series)
    except Exception:
        pass

    if is_reduction:
        return Series(NA, index=self._get_agg_axis(axis))
    else:
        return self.copy()
```

So, in fact, Pandas is trying to be smart and guess whether it should return a `DataFrame` or a `Series`, and the exception is throwing things off.

I suppose a patch is in order.